# Azure DevOps connectivity to Gearset

Tags: azure-devops

I am having issues with accessing Azure DevOps in Gearset and after some research (https://docs.gearset.com/en/articles/2699339-does-your-azure-devops-connection-not-find-all-the-repositories-or-organizations) I believe it is because I have multiple (two) tenants in Azure DevOps and my Gearset is therefore being connected to the wrong one. How do I delete the unwanted one?

I have tried to delete the unwanted tenant/Azure DevOps organisation and I am not able to.

Comment: "I have tried to delete the unwanted tenant...and I am not able to" What do you mean you were not able to? Did you get an error message? If so what was it? Were you using the Azure DevOps REST API or something else to delete the tenant?

Comment: Hello, I see no option to delete the tenant or to leave the project.